# Capability exchange fails between erlang client and seagull server

Tags: erlang, client-server, 4g, diameter-protocol

I have an erlang client and seagull server. When `CER` is sent by erlang and its captured by seagull server. `Hop-by-Hop` and `End-to-End` identifiers are same in captured pcap file.

But erlang client keeps sending `CER` to seagull and seagull server does not capture them.

`gen_server` -> `handle_info` returns timeout

> {diameter_event,sy_server,
>                      {closed,#Ref<0.2013523099.132382721.94052>,
>                          {'CEA',timeout},
>                          {connect,
>                              [{connect_timer,200},
>                               {transport_module,diameter_tcp},
>                               {transport_config,
>                                   [{reuseaddr,true},
>                                    {raddr,{127,0,0,1}},
>                                    {rport,3876}]}]}}} : State []
>
> {diameter_event,sy_server,
>                      {reconnect,#Ref<0.2013523099.132382721.94052>,
>                          [{connect_timer,200},
>                           {transport_module,diameter_tcp},
>                           {transport_config,
>                               [{reuseaddr,true},
>                                {raddr,{127,0,0,1}},
>                                {rport,3876}]}]}} : State []

I am trying to send `SLR` from erlang node to seagull server, but `peer-up` does not working.
How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you capture the traffic on both sides? Maybe the CER is not reaching the server.

Comment: @delephin No, it reaches. `peer_up` in erlang side works.

Comment: Did you get any kind of log from the server side? It seems like the connection is ended before the diameter server can send an answer, otherwise you'll be receiving a CEA, so I'd look in the tcp configuration. In your tcp dumps, which side is ending the connection?

Comment: @delephin I get `CEA` from seagull, but its when I send `SLR` from erlang to seagull server, its not received.

Comment: Are you receiving DWR and DWA?

Comment: @delephin `DWR` is sent, but not answered by seagull side with `DWA`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190804/discussion-between-delephin-and-sachith).